# Did Harry have the Marauder's Map at any point where Scabbers was with Ron?

Tags: harry-potter, marauders-map

I'm a little lost about Prisoner of Azkaban's timeline. Did Scabbers disappear prior to Harry losing the Marauder's Map? What chapters should I be looking at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Harry did have the map when Scabbers was with Ron.

He loses the map in chapter 14 : Snape's Grudge.

Scabbers dissappears in chapter 12.

Harry gets the map in chapter 10

Hope that this answers your question

EDIT : So yes,  Scabbers disappeared before Harry lost the map.